# DropDownList is not showing the Selected Value in EditItemTemplate of RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, radgrid

I am using asp DropDownList inside RadGrid, and trying to Add and Update the DropDownList item inside Database table.

Below is the HTML code for DropDownList inside RadGrid's EditItemTemplate:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode")%>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>'></asp:Label>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAcCode" DataTextField="AccountDescription" DataValueField="AccountCodeID" runat="server"/> 
       </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

**C# Code:**

```
    public DataTable GetAccCode(string CompanyCode)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Invoice].[usp_tbl_AccountCode_DL_Test]", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyCode", CompanyCode);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return dt;
        }

    protected void RGGSTAcCode_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {

           if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
                {
                    //bind dropdwon while "Add" 
                    string CompanyCode = ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
                    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlAcCode");
                    ddl.DataSource = GetAccCode(CompanyCode);
                    ddl.DataTextField = "AccountDescription";
                    ddl.DataValueField = "AccountCodeID";
                    ddl.DataBind();
                    ddl.Items.Insert(0, "- Select -");

                    //Select particular dropdown value while "Edit"
                    string accCodeID =  item.GetDataKeyValue("AccountCodeID").ToString();
                    Label lblAcCode2 = item.FindControl("lblAcCode") as Label;

                    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblAcCode2.Text))
                    //{
                        ddl.SelectedValue = lblAcCode2.Text;
                    //}
                    //string SelectedVal =  ddl.SelectedValue;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblAcCode2.Text))
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [AccountCode]+' - '+[AccountDescription] as [AccountDescription] FROM [Sunway_AP].[Invoice].[tbl_AccountCodeTest] where AccountCodeID='" + accCodeID + "' ", con);

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    try
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    ddl.SelectedValue = dt.ToString();
                    string SelectedVal = ddl.SelectedValue;
                }

             }
         }
```

**This is the Stored Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Invoice].[usp_tbl_AccountCode_DL_Test]
    @CompanyCode nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   
       SELECT [AccountCodeID] ,[AccountCode]+' - '+[AccountDescription] as [AccountDescription]     
       FROM [Sunway_AP].[General].[tbl_AccountCode] (NOLOCK)
       Where [CompanyCode] = @CompanyCode
       order by [AccountCode]+' - '+[AccountDescription]

END
```

My problem is: I am unable to fetch the "DropDownList's" selected value for a particular Id (particular row of RadGrid), while Edit.
Everytime when I try to set the Selected Value of DropdownList from code behind, it shows me 1st item '- Select -' inside the selected value.

Please reply what is wrong in my code.
I am very new in Telerik. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified my posted code as below:

```
protected void RGGSTAcCode_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {

       if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
            {
                //bind dropdwon while "Add" 
                string CompanyCode = ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();
                GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlAcCode");
                ddl.DataSource = GetAccCode(CompanyCode);
                ddl.DataTextField="*your text field*";
                ddl.DataValueField="*your Value field*";
                ddl.DataBind();
                ddl.Items.Insert(0, "- Select -");

               Label lblAcCode2 = item.FindControl("lblAcCode2") as Label;
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblAcCode2.Text))
               {
                  ddl.SelectedItem.Text = lblAcCode2.Text;
                  ddl.SelectedValue = lblAcCode2.Text;
               }
           }
     }

    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode")%>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAcCode" DataTextField="AccountDescription" DataValueField="AccountCodeID" runat="server"/> 
       </EditItemTemplate>
   </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Hope this helps...

All the best...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I made the changes suggested by you (please check my updated posted code). But still I am facing same issue. When I try to debug my code, every time I see that in `ddl.SelectedValue`, "- Select -" is coming, not the particular Id's/row's DropDownList Item (which is saved in DB). Please suggest what shall I do ?

Comment: Also, I am getting expected output inside Label "lblAcCode2" but not in DropDownList (for particular row/Id). In DropDownList it always shows "- Select -" in ddl.SelectedValue

Comment: I want some details about the code. Can you Explain?                          what the method GetAccCode(CompanyCode); returns?

Comment: `GetAccCode(CompanyCode)` method is used to bind the DropDownList based on "CompanyCode" using Stored Procedure. Please check the posted question I had updated this method into it.

Comment: It sounds all are fine. Try autopostback="true" in the dropdownlist this may helps....

Comment: Yes. Thatswhat I am unable to understand why DropDownList is not showing expected result. I am getting expected output inside Label "lblAcCode2" but not in DropDownList (for particular row/Id). In DropDownList it always shows "- Select -" in ddl.SelectedValue . Is there any other way I can try ? Please reply Also, I tried `autopostback="true"` in the dropdownlist but not working as per expected. Please reply what shall I do

Comment: Can you please create a demo using my code and test at your end why its not working as per required ? Please reply I am stuck in this from 2 days. Please check my posted question I have modified it with 1 more solution but still not working.

Comment: I have one doubt in your code, what value is present in the lblAcCode2.Text? before the following code execute  "ddl.SelectedValue = lblAcCode2.Text;"

Comment: "lblAcCode2" is a Label inside EditItemTemplate just above the DropDown, I placed it just to check the desired result which is suppose to come in DropDown. I have no clue why its not working. I tried every possible way. Im stuck in this from past 3 days. Please run my code at your side and let me know my mistake. Even `ddl.SelectedValue = dt.ToString();` line is also not giving correct result although `dt` has correct data in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83188/discussion-between-sankar-and-user3196511).

Comment: Added a Label inside EditItemtemplate before DropDownList, to bind the data of particular Id/row DropDownList item inside Label. And changed the c# code accordingly. Its working fine now. (Modifed the Sankar's code as per what I did) Thankyou @Sankar for the help